# Marker onPress updating state in android but not in ios

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using React native map, In that I use Marker onPress which sets my const [ind,setInd]=useState() , The onPress just works fine in android but in ios it is not updating my const [ind,setInd]=useState()

```
<Marker
    coordinate={{...coordinate}}
    flat={true}
    onPress={i => {
      setInd(i);
       mapView?.current?.animateToRegion(
        {
          ...coordinate,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        },
        1000,
      );
    }}>
```

although map is animating to region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `onPress={(e)=>{ e.stopPropagation() setInd(i); mapView?.current?.animateToRegion( { ...coordinate, latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA, longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA, }, 1000, ); }`
e.stopPropagation() solved my question